# How to make a particular Text Bold after a Text

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a sample text.
var sample="id:123 Hello How are you id:456 I am fine".

123 and 456 are ids. There can be multiple ids in a sentence. 
So, How to make every id bold in the sentence.
And then after that how to remove "id:" from the sample text.

Comment: Use JS string template.

Comment: Where does this string and ids come from? It can be done but it's somewhat complicated and might require some regex rules and a `str.replace()` function. In this particular example where you are declaring the string statically you could just use `var sample="<strong>123</strong> Hello How are you <strong>456</strong> I am fine"` but I'm guessing you haven't provided the complete use case in this question.

Comment: string and id is coming as json data.

Answer (score 3):

If you're comfortable with using a bit of regular expressions, this snippet will wrap the IDs in a `<strong>` element and remove the leading `id:`.

```
var sample = "id:123 Hello How are you id:456 I am fine";
var converted = sample.replace(/id:(\d+)/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
```

**Explanation:** The content between the slashes - `/id:(\d+)/g` is regex that:

1. `id:` Finds an instance of `id:`
2. `(\d+)` is followed by one or more numerical characters, and stores that in reference $1
3. `g` does a global search, replacing all instances rather than just the first.

Comment: It is not necessary that after "id:" there will be only numerical characters. There can be string characters also. Example id:122str. How to do it then

Comment: If you want to match other word characters, use \w (alphanumeric match) instead of \d (numeric match)

Answer (score 0):

You can give every id that you want bold a class and then bold it in a css file.

You can write a function to strip the unwanted "id:", though if you show more code I can give you a more accurate answer.